# Python spyder IDE beginner -error in for loop defining

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

nu = 0.05
N=1.5
Nt=8192
alpha = pow(math.pi,2)*pow(nu,2)
n=Nt/2
t= np.arange(-n,n)+Nt/6
A=np.array([1,0.33,0.12])
f=np.array([31, 84, 88])
w= nu*math.sqrt(math.pi)/2*np.exp(-alpha * pow(t,2))*(1-2*alpha*pow(t,2))
s=np.zeros((Nt,1))
for i in range(len(A))
s=s+A[i]*math.sin(2*math.pi*f[i]*(0:Nt))
```

Can someone please help me to write this (0:Nt) - matlab command into python?

Comment: Did you mean to do `s=s+i`?

Comment: I think you mean just `for i in A: s=s+i`. `i` is the element itself, not the index.

Comment: Hi , This is the matlab code I need to convert into Python    for i=1:length(A), 
     s=s+A(i)*sin(2*%pi*f(i)*(0:Nt-1)*dt)';
end